# Unity texture from disk has low resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine, png, textures, sprite

I am trying to load a texture(and create a sprite from it eventually) from disk but sprite renders as low resolution image.

What I am doing:

-> Download the image from url. Once the image is downloaded, I save the texture as png to disk so that next time it doesn't requires a download.

```
WWW www = new WWW(url);
yield return www;

if (www.isDone)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Sprite img = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0,   www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));
                reward.RewardSprite = img;

         byte[] bytes = www.texture.EncodeToPNG();
         FileManager.SaveRewardImage(reward.rewardId, bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
 }
```

-> Load from disk

```
string path = string.Format("Cache\\Venue\\{0}", nameWithoutExtension);

return Resources.Load<Texture2D>(path);
```

The first time when the texture loads from url, its resolution seems fine(because its the original one). When it loads from cache, it attenuates to a lower one.
Can someone tell me what am I missing, or even if there is way around it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run this second time check in Inspector properties of imported .png image. Most likely compression and bit size need adjustments

Answer (score 0):

You can overload your texture in your sprite creation in the same way that you do with the rectangle and specify in [TextureFormat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html) the format you need:

```
Sprite img = Sprite.Create(
new Texture2D (www.texture.width, www.texture.height, TextureFormat format, bool mipmap),
new Rect(0, 0,   www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));
```

Comment: Hi, the low res images were showing due to generate mip maps which was checked when saving to disk. The problem is, even if I use the above method (with bool mipmap), it still creates a sprite with "generate mip maps" checked.